# Can I install Unity in Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows IOT?

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, unity-game-engine, raspberry-pi3

I would like to create a Raspberry Pi 3 server with Win IOT as its OS for our git repositories and unity to build apps that are being developed in our desktop computers. Is this possible? thank you.

Comment: Not with IoT at the moment. It is very limited really. But you can do it with Raspbian or Ubuntu